# Ошибка при построении диаграммы рассеивания: KeyError: 'class'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, визуализация

Мой код:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url,sep=';')

col1 = 'fixed acidity'
col2 = 'volatile acidity'

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.scatter(data[col1][data['class'] == '+'],
            data[col2][data['class'] == '+'],
            alpha=0.75,
            color='red',
            label='+')

plt.scatter(data[col1][data['class'] == '-'],
            data[col2][data['class'] == '-'],
            alpha=0.75,
            color='blue',
            label='-')

plt.xlabel(col1)
plt.ylabel(col2)
plt.legend(loc='best');
```

При выполнении кода выбрасывается исключение `KeyError: 'class'`.

В чём ошибка? Что нужно поставить на место `'class'`?

Comment: ну посмотри, что содержится в data.

Comment: смотрю и легче не становится

Comment: в вашем датасете нет столбца с названием `class` - об этом вам и сообщает ошибка )

Comment: мы не можем вам сказать что нужно поставить на место `class`, т.к. нам не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать. В вашем датасете также нет столбца, содержащего плюсы и минусы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить, что вы хотели нарисовать как соотносятся два указанных признака для белых и красных сортов вина:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-{}.csv"
red = pd.read_csv(url.format("red"), sep=";")
white = pd.read_csv(url.format("white"), sep=";")

col1 = 'fixed acidity'
col2 = 'volatile acidity'

ax = red.plot.scatter(
    x=col1, y=col2, c="purple", edgecolors="silver", 
    figsize=(10, 10), s=30, label="red", grid=True)
white.plot.scatter(
    x=col1, y=col2, c="beige", ax=ax, edgecolors="silver", 
    s=30, label="white")
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Можно выбрать любую пару признаков и нарисовать диаграмму рассеяния для этой пары признаков, изображая точки, соответствующие объектам из разных классов разным цветом: + – красный, - – синий." Прочитала это в в статье, которую дали в вузе. Тип с помощью этой диаграммы можно увидеть, какой признак является существенным. Написала по образцу и была ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Создается стойкое впечатление, что вы взяли какой-то код, даже не дали себе труд разобраться что он делает, запулили в него данные, получили ошибку и вместо того, что-бе подумать - побежали сюда за помощью. Что-то SW все больше превращается в сайт для решения домашних заданий нерадивых школьников.

Ну ответе, откуда у вас в коде взялся 'class' да еще с плюсиками и минусиками в придачу.
Мы не понимаем, что вы там вроде-как надумали делать, но базовый код у вас абсолютно рабочий:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url,sep=';')
col1 = 'fixed acidity'
col2 = 'volatile acidity'
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.scatter(data[col1],
        data[col2],
        alpha=0.75,
        color='blue',
        label='-')
plt.xlabel(col1)
plt.ylabel(col2)
plt.legend(loc='best');
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А дальше - думайте сами.